# Use Link_to helper to go to a div on a different page rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a div with an id on a certain page. I want to use a link_to and link to the other page by the rails path but specifically to that id.

Here is how i have it but it is not correct.

```
<%= link_to "Pricing", welcome_index_path#pricingslide, class: "nav-item nav-link" %>
```

Not sure of the proper syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like anchor option in path helpers can help you achieve it, e.g.

```
redirect_to comment_path(@article.comment, anchor: 'some-id')
```

Comment: That got it! Thanks! Here is how I did it. `<%= link_to "Pricing", welcome_index_path(anchor: 'pricingslide'), class: "nav-item nav-link" %>`